# Find all ajax requests being made - htmlunit

Tags: ajax, htmlunit

Using htmlunit is there anyway to log all ajax requests that are being made from the requested page when javascript execution is enabled?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can configure HTMLUnit with a proxy that makes traffic go through Fiddler, that way you can see all the requests that are made with htmlunit.

```
        BrowserVersion bv = BrowserVersion.CHROME;
        webClient = new WebClient(bv, "127.0.0.1", 8888);
```